# Post xml request over telnet on aix

Tags: linux, telnet, aix

I am trying to post xml request using telnet on AIX machine. I am using following command

**cat filename | telnet hostip hostport**

Request is going to server and response is also coming back to machine but telnet is not receiving that response.

Same command is working fine with HP-UX machine and telnet is receiving response.

As soon as I hit enter I see connection closed message on AIX machine. while on HP-UX I can see response.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Post?  as in an HTTP post request?  Is file name a list of commands?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: There is issue in pipeline output with telnet on AIX.. If I use delay then I could see response before command quits..otherwise command suppresses the display..